# Loop, compare to macro value in condition and multiple macros if true

Tags: macros, loops

I seem to be stuck and for now am trying my luck through trial and error to find the right way to do this.

Here is a general idea:

```
% I DECLARE NEW MACROS WITH NAMES AS DEFFINITION. AND ASIGN LETTERS TO PEOPLE SINCE NUMBERS ARE FORBIDEN IN MACRO'S NAMES.
\newcommand{\AuthorNameA}{John}
\newcommand{\AuthorSurnameA}{Doe}
\newcommand{\AuthorNameB}{Jane}
\newcommand{\AuthorSurnameB}{Doe}
\newcommand{\AuthorNumber}{3}

% DECLARE NEW COUNTER
\newcounter{loopTitleCoverAuthor}

% START WITH LOOP
\forloop{loopTitleCoverAuthor}{1}{

   %COMPARE COUNTER WITH DEFINITION OF MACRO SET PREVIOUSLY
   \value{loopTitleCoverAuthor} < \value{bfThesisAuthorNumber}
}{
% IF CONDITION IS TRUE CHECK IF MACRO WITH PARTICULLAR ENDING IS DEFINED AND IF IT IS, PRINT NAME AND SURNAME
\ifdefined\expandafter\AuthorName\Alph{loopTitleCoverAuthor}
   \expandafter\AuthorName\Alph{loopTitleCoverAuthor} \textsc{\expandafter\AuthorSurname\Alph{loopTitleCoverAuthor}}\\
\fi
}
```

a) Not surprisingly that didn't work. The first issue I got was comparing the counter to a macro value. So to continue and to see what else might be wrong I changed condition part to:

```
\value{loopTitleCoverAuthor} < 3 %\value{bfThesisAuthorNumber}
```

b) Then I had a problem with `\ifdefined` check so I commented that out too and name and surname macros are always called.

c) Lastly I had a problem with `\expandafter` (I think). I now get output, but not as it should be. It omits `\AuthorName` and `\AuthorSurname` and prints only `\Alph` of the counter step.

I would expect to see:

```
John Doe
Jane Doe
```

I get:

```
AA
BB
```

So, those are my questions:

1. Is it possible to use a value of macro in the condition of `\forloop`(a)?
2. How should I reformat `\ifdefined` to check properly if macro is defined in each loop (`\AuthorNameA` in first loop, `\AuthorNameB` in second ...) (b)? I also tried with `\csname`, multiple \expandafter, `\expandafter` before `\ifdefined`, ... Nothing described here: https://www.tug.org/TUGboat/tb09-1/tb20bechtolsheim.pdf seems to work (or more likely I'm doing something obviously wrong and can't see it).
3. What should I change so that `\AuthorNameA` gets expanded (c)?
4. Is there a generally better way to do this? Declare "controls and variables" in one file and then `\input` that file and use values of those macros in loops to display and control output?

Comment: What is the `bfThesisAuthorNumber` I don't see any definition.

Comment: What I learned just the other day, is that if you use `\ifdefined\csname...` you always get true. If the function in `\csname` is undefined, it returns `\relax`. That means, it should be `\expandafter\ifx\csname someStuff\endcsname\relax (You compare the macro with `\relax`). I don't get the question exactly, so I write this as a comment first.

Comment: @MaestroGlanz You can do `\ifcsname...\endcsname` that returns true if the control sequence that would be obtained by `\csname...\endcsname` has a meaning and false otherwise, but *without* making it equivalent to `\relax`.

Comment: @MaestroGlanz It's a typo. My apologies. I shortened my code for easier read but missed that one. It should be just \AuthorNumber. Thank you for your help and time!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The test `\value{A} < \value{B}` works for me.

I've used `\@ifundefined{csname}{true}{false}` where `csname` is the command name to be tested without the escape character `\`.

The most important thing here is constructing the various command names, with `\csname foo\Alph{...}\endcsname`.

```
\documentclass{article}


\usepackage{forloop}

\newcommand{\AuthorNameA}{John}
\newcommand{\AuthorSurnameA}{Doe}
\newcommand{\AuthorNameB}{Jane}
\newcommand{\AuthorSurnameB}{Doe}
\newcommand{\AuthorNumber}{5}

% DECLARE NEW COUNTER
\newcounter{loopTitleCoverAuthor}

\newcounter{bfThesisAuthorNumber}
\setcounter{bfThesisAuthorNumber}{\AuthorNumber}


\begin{document}
% START WITH LOOP
\makeatletter 
\forloop{loopTitleCoverAuthor}{1}{%
  % COMPARE COUNTER WITH DEFINITION OF MACRO SET PREVIOUSLY
  \value{loopTitleCoverAuthor} < \value{bfThesisAuthorNumber} % End condition
}{
  \@ifundefined{AuthorName\Alph{loopTitleCoverAuthor}}{%
    Booooooooooooo: Author \Alph{loopTitleCoverAuthor} is not defined!

  }{
    Hooray:  Author \Alph{loopTitleCoverAuthor} exists and is \csname AuthorName\Alph{loopTitleCoverAuthor}\endcsname 

    \csname AuthorName\Alph{loopTitleCoverAuthor}\endcsname\ \textsc{\csname AuthorSurname\Alph{loopTitleCoverAuthor}\endcsname}

  }
}
\makeatother    
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! I managed to merge your example with my production code and now it works. Especially \setcounter{bfThesisAuthorNumber}{\AuthorNumber}, ifundefined and  csname parts were very helpfull since I wasn't sure what syntax should be. And then, sure enough, I wrote it all wrong and nothing worked. All sorted now, so thanks again!

Comment: @NejcDraganjec: You're welcome! Happy TeXing!

Answer (score 2):

There are a few problems with your code.

1. The code

   ```
   \ifdefined\expandafter\AuthorName\Alph{loopTitleCoverAuthor}
   ```

   tests whether `\expandafter` is defined.
2. However the code

   ```
   \expandafter\ifdefined\expandafter\AuthorName\Alph{loopTitleCoverAuthor}
   ```

   would do no good either, because you'd get, when `loopTitleCoverAuthor` has the value 1,

   ```
   \ifdefined\AuthorName A
   ```

   and not a single token as you're hoping to.
3. Similarly, when you do

   ```
    \expandafter\AuthorName\Alph{loopTitleCoverAuthor}
   ```

   in the true part, you get *two* tokens, not `\AuthorNameA`.

How can you do?

The trick is using `\ifcsname` and `\csname`. You *first* want to produce a token whose name consists of `AuthorName` followed by the alphabetical value of the counter:

```
\ifcsname AuthorName\Alph{loopTitleCoverAuthor}\endcsname
  \expandafter\AuthorName\Alph{loopTitleCoverAuthor}
  \textsc{\csname AuthorSurname\Alph{loopTitleCoverAuthor}\endcsname}\\
\fi
```

No `\expandafter` is needed, because `\ifcsname` and `\csname` perform full expansion until the matching `\endcsname` is found.

Comment: Bonus points for kind explanation. If I could I would accept 2 answers as this one would surely also brought me to a working document. Thank you!

Comment: @NejcDraganjec Don't worry! I'm no short in rep. `;-)`

Answer (score 1):

Though there are already good answers, I contribute the version, I used for my currently growing Liederbuch-package:

```
\def\TesT#1{
\expandafter\def\csname test\Alph{#1}\endcsname{}
}

\newcounter{wseva}
\setcounter{wseva}{4}

\TesT{wseva}

\def\doesItExist#1{
\expandafter\ifx\csname test\Alph{#1}\endcsname\relax
no
\else
yes
\fi
}

\begin{document}

\doesItExist{wseva}

\end{document}
```

If the content of `\csname` doesnt exist, it returns `\relax`. The comparison `\ifx\theExpandedCsname\relax` return true. Otherwise it returns false and the `\else` part will be run.

Comment: What happens if you say `\doesitexist{undefined}\doesitexist{undefined}`?

Comment: @Manuel You have to make a counter named `undefined` first. Then it says `no`.